# Ubuntu 14.10 Install Fails to boot

Tags: boot, 14.10

I have tried to do a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.10 on a 64bit-AMD (toshiba-satalite), from an liveCD ( that I made on a usb drive). I am able to launch the live CD, and install from there, but fails after boot - saying that it can't find any boot media.

"Checking media presence....
 No media present"

"reboot and select proper boot device it insert boy media in selected boot  and press a key"

I have tried following the general advice on boot-repair, but after installing, and running even that has failed with the following report http://paste.ubuntu.com/9063443/.

I have also tried to change boot order since I did set the USB to primary.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Same here, the boot process stucks, I need to edit the grub and use the options `noapic`,  `acpi=off` and `pnpbios=off` (found that in `dmesg`) otherwise the system won't start up.

Found it out, the boot process gets stuck because of wrong settings, therefore you have to edit the file grub.cfg, in my case I added the options needed.

```
noapic acpi=off
```

Now, my notebook starts up, now in dmesg the warning about pnpbios comes up, when I set this off, then again it stucks, so better leave it on.

Comment: Instead of editing `grub.cfg`, which gets regenerated frequently, directly, you should edit the file `/etc/default/grub` and add the parameters between the quotes in the line that begins `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=`, and then run the command `sudo update grub`.

Answer (score 0):

You've got an EFI system.  Did you follow https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI from the official Ubuntu help pages when you installed your system?

Comment: I believe yes.. but clearly the answer must be no :) .. I have mailed my latest pastbin errors to the support mail of boot-repair -- hopfully they can expose my ignorance.

Comment: An upvote on my answer would be nice.  ;)
And post back here after you've received more data...
As I've never installed an EFI system, I can't give you an expert opinion, but I know a lot about the boot process...